# Use pre-populated database with ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to ship my app with a big database inside the assets folder. The [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) seems to be the solution for this.

However, the app also uses ormlite and it has a lot of Java objects that map to the tables of the database. How can I make ormlite use the pre-populated database?

Comment: did you find a good solution?

Comment: I've taken some of the code from the SQliteAssetHelper and added inside my own class that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper and adapted it. And it worked.

Comment: can you share your work or more description? i want to develop my app with SqliteAssetHelper for prepopulated DB and upgrading dbs , and an ORM for data acess,ORMlite or GreenDao.can you explain more or answer your question?

Comment: Sorry. I can't give more details because the code is old and I do not remember exactly what other modifications I have made. But it wasn't anything complicated. Try to do what I have said in my answer and I am confident you will make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own SqliteOpenHelper that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper and then, inside I have copied the code present in SQLiteAssetHelper.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of SQLiteAssetHelper and implement this [DatabaseInitializer class](https://github.com/bfil/android-ormlite-sample/blob/master/src/com/bfil/ormliterepo/data/DatabaseInitializer.java) which copies your db (if it doesn't exist) to `data/data/yourapp/databases/yourdb.db` (folder where ormlite generates your db)

In your DatabaseHelper constructor:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    DatabaseInitializer initializer = new DatabaseInitializer(context);
    try {
        initializer.createDatabase();
        initializer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Clean & simple solution

Some minor cons :
 - works only with Android 2.2.3+
 - be careful with the size (didn't encounter any problem with 3mb)